# wso2 foreach loop never goes in

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm trying to get a wso2 foreach loop to work.

```
<property expression="$ctx:xmlTransform"
```

Value of $ctx:xmlTransform :

```
<magasin>
  <codeMagasin>20019</codeMagasin>
</magasin>
<magasin>
  <codeMagasin>20020</codeMagasin>
</magasin>
<magasin>
  <codeMagasin>20021</codeMagasin>
</magasin>
```

Loop :

```
<foreach expression="$ctx:xmlTransform//magasin" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd">
        <sequence>
            <log category="ERROR">
                <property expression="tessst" name="----Test foreach loop----"/>
            </log>
        </sequence>
</foreach>
```

I'm never going inside the loop.

Any ideas ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if you are adding the correct XPATH expression for the for loop. You can do this by adding a log mediator.

```
<log level="custom">
       <property expression="$ctx:xmlTransform" name="----log----"/>
</log>
```

This need to print the following in order for the for loop to work. Otherwise there is an issue with the XPATH expression you have used.

```
INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - ----log---- = <magasin>
                            <codeMagasin>20019</codeMagasin>
                        </magasin><magasin>
                            <codeMagasin>20020</codeMagasin>
                        </magasin><magasin>
                            <codeMagasin>20021</codeMagasin>
                        </magasin>
```

For example if you need to get the content from a request, the XPATH need to be modified as `<foreach expression="$body//magasin">`. I have sent the following payload from a postman request and it seems to be working for me without any issue. Therefore I am suspecting that the issue is with the XPATH expression you used.

Postman request body

```
<xmlTransform>
   <magasin>
      <codeMagasin>20019</codeMagasin>
   </magasin>
   <magasin>
      <codeMagasin>20020</codeMagasin>
   </magasin>
   <magasin>
      <codeMagasin>20021</codeMagasin>
   </magasin>
</xmlTransform>
```

Proxy service

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="DummyProxy" startOnLoad="true" statistics="disable" trace="disable" transports="http,https">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="$body//magasin" name="----log----"/>
            </log>
            <foreach expression="$body//magasin">
                <sequence>
                    <log>
                        <property name="----Test foreach loop----" value="tessst"/>
                    </log>
                </sequence>
            </foreach>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
    </target>
    <description/>
</proxy>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes the xpath is fine, it prints everything good. But the foreach still doesn't work. Never goes inside.

<log category="ERROR" level="custom">
       <property expression="$ctx:xmlTransform" name="----log----"/>
</log>

<foreach
        expression="$ctx:xmlTransform//magasin" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd">

Comment: what is the EI version you are using.

Comment: We are using 6.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that "magasin" nodes are not enclosed in one parent element. Try to wrap it with some parent element (ex. box), replace body with the one with parent element and then run the loop.

```
<enrich>
  <source type="inline" clone="true">
    <ns:box xmlns:ns="http://namespace"/>
  </source>
  <target type="property" property="box"/>
</enrich>
<enrich>
  <source clone="true" xpath="$ctx:xmlTransform"/>
  <target action="child" xpath="$ctx:box"/>
</enrich>
<enrich>
  <source type="property" clone="true" property="box"/>
  <target action="replace" type="body"/>
</enrich>
<foreach expression="//ns:box/magasin" xmlns:ns="http://namespace">
  <sequence>
    <log category="ERROR">
      <property expression="tessst" name="----Test foreach loop----"/>
    </log>
  </sequence>
</foreach>
```